# No internet access on VM in ESXi

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have recently started using VMware ESXi for testing and have created a VM running Windows Server 2008 R2. And for some reasons I'm not able to get internet on the VM, I have added the failover IP net mask and gateway to the Windows network settings page and have also added the mac address of the failover IP to ESXi vm configuration page but it still doesn't work. I have also asked the DC to replace the failover IP but still no luck. Also, I'm not able to ping anything from inside the VM.

Here are some screenshots which may help:

Network: http://prntscr.com/cfdsv0
Windows Network Settings: http://prntscr.com/cfdu21

The host is a dedicated server and I have no physical access to it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with some details? - Is the VM IP on the same network as the host? - Can you ping Gateway from inside the VM?

Comment: I have assigned the VM IP as a failover IP to the server (host) from my DC's control panel. So that means it's on the same network? And no, I can't ping the gateway.

Comment: Thats a pretty simple setup on the ESX so side so I would assume thats some wrong on the DC side. Hit them with a ticket regarding this.

Comment: I have already contacted the DC and the only solution they could offer is the replacement of failover IP

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Maybe you're thinking of a failover *network adapter* in the ESXi host machine.
But yes, the ESXi host and virtual machine are to be treated as two individual machines the same as two physical machines when you configure them. So, you need a separate address for each. Maybe that's what you meant. I've edited this answer because I think I was confused. And now I agree that probably the network mask and/or address in use is causing at least part of the problem.
The ESXi host must have access to whatever you're trying to reach.
You shouldn't have to be messing with MAC addresses.

Comment: OK maybe it's confusing for you, let me put it in a simple way. Here is what I'm trying to achieve. Remember this is the first time I'm using ESXi so I'm not an expert at all. So I have installed ESXi on my server using DC's dedicated server control panel and logged into it using Vsphere client and created a Windows 2008 R2 machine. Before starting the whole thing I read somewhere that I will be needing more than 1 IP address to have access to ESXi  host and ESXI VM so I bought a new IP and added it to the windows VM. I just want to create a windows VM and have RDP access to it. That's it.

Comment: A 32-bit mask means that the VM cannot communicate with *anything* except itself.  You need a 31-bit mask or smaller in order to reach the gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the mac address of the IP has fixed the issue.